# Incompatible peer dependency while migrating old angular project

Tags: angular

```
Package "angular2-grid" has an incompatible peer dependency to "zone.js" (requires "^0.7.2", would install "0.8.26").
Package "angular2-grid" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.0.1", would install "6.2.0").
Package "ngx-dropdown" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=3.0.0-rc.0 <4.0.0||>=2.0.0 <3.0.0", would install "6.0.4").
```

Migrating old angular project. what to do?

Comment: have you tried updating the packages first?

Comment: yes, ng update @angular/core but it did not work

Comment: Not angular... the **libraries**.  The ones that are complaining.   ‘Angular2-grid’ and ‘ngx-drop down’

Comment: solved by updating rxjs and zone.js